# How to remove cucumber tags from extent report

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, pom.xml, extentreports

Few of my tcs in cucumber feature file are having multiple tags like @smoke, @regression, @homePage, @e2e.What Im trying to achieve is when I trigger tcs based on smoke tag and after extent report is generated, all the above tags are present in extent report. How to achieve only one tag.

Only one tag in which we have triggered the tc like in here smoke tag
Instead of all 4 tags

Comment: can you provide more code as to how you are assigning Category to the test

Answer (score 0):

You should provide more code example as to how you are assigning Category to the test
ExtentTest Class has a assignCategory() which accepts a String array in which you would be passing your categories which are then shown in the report, can you check this in your code and then only pass the Category that you need